# Implementing custom back button for android

Tags: android

I'm making custom navigation buttons which can implement the functionality of back, home and recent apps button. Right now, i have implemented to code of home and recent apps button but unable to implement code of back button. I have disabled my default navigation buttons. Is there anyway to implements this?

Thanks

Comment: you can call MyActivity.this.onBackPressed() inside your Button onClick() callBack.

Answer (score 0):

call finish() on the button onclick handler

Comment: I'm not making it as an activity where I can receive the this.onBackPressed(). I can be on my home-screen or on my launcher menu . I want to go back to home-screen from launcher menu without using default android provided navigation buttons. How can I do it?